# How do I handle a large number of files as an input to a build when using VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

To set expectations, I'm new to build tooling. We're currently using a hosted agent but we're open to other options.

We've got a local application that kicks off a build using the VSTS API. The hosted build tasks involve the **Get sources** step from a GitHub repo to the local file system in VSO. The next step we need to copy over a large number of files (upwards of about 10000 files), building the solution, and running the tests.

The problem is that the cloned GitHub repo is in the file system in Visual Studio Online, and my 10000 input files are on a local machine. That seems like a bit much, especially since we plan on doing CI and may have many builds being kicked off per day.

What is the best way to move the input files into the cloned repo so that we can build it? Should we be using a hosted agent for this? Or is it best to do this on our local system? I've looked in the [VSO docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview) but haven't found an answer there. I'm not sure if I asking the right questions here.

Comment: What are the files? I assume they are not code, but what kind of content are they?

Comment: They are code files that must be a part of the build. We are generating the code files from metadata and templates so even minor changes can result in changes to 100s of files.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to handle the situation, you can follow the way which is closest to your situations.

#### Option 1.    Add the large files to the github repo

If the local files are only related to the code of the github repo, you should add the files into the same repo so that all the required files will be cloned in **Get Sources** step, then you can build directly without copy files step.

#### Option 2.    Manage the large files in another git repo, and then add the git repo as submodule for the github repo

If the local large files are also used for other code, you can manage the large files in a separate repo, and treat it as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for github repo by `git submodule add <URL for the separate repo>`. And in your VSTS build definition, select **Checkout submodules** in Get sources step. Then the large files can be used directly when you build the github code.

[image]

#### Option 3.    Use private agent on your local machine

If you don’t want add the large files in the github repo or a separate git repo for some reasons, you can use a private agent instead. But the **build run time may not improve obviously**, because the changed run time is only the different between **copying local files to server** and **copying local files to the same local machine**.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. The submodule and using a private agent options have potential for us. Another option is that we use the Get sources step more than we are using it now. One of the remote git repos, when built, takes a single file input and outputs a large number of files which are then subsequently combined with the contents of another repo and then built. I think you have helped move us forward a bit. Thank you.